# AnimatedModel - Multiple model box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to run multiple model lightbox for multiple content using the plugin [Animated Model](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/)

It works with the one link, but when I try to make a duplicate box it doesn't work, I think because of the model target ID defined in the JS, here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le70m4ht/)

Can anyone please suggest how can I make multiple model boxes using this plugin?

```
<a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a> 
<div id="animatedModal"> 
  <div class="close-animatedModal"> CLOSE MODAL </div>
  <div class="modal-content"> 
    modal content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in ur fiddle, 2 elements are having same ID's, which should not happen as every element should have a unique ID in a document and you can Have a look at my fiddle here - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatpatel06/Le70m4ht/2/)

with js

```
 //demo 01
  $("#demo01").animatedModal();

  //demo 02
  $("#demo02").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: 'animatedModal2'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this code:-

```
$("#demo02").animatedModal({
            modalTarget:'modal-02',
            animatedIn:'lightSpeedIn',
            animatedOut:'bounceOutDown',
            color:'#3498db'                
        });
```